django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'tools.User' that has not been installed
I want to replace the original User of django with my own User, but the following error occurred
This is my settings.py，I mainly addedv AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'tools.User'
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

import django

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    "daphne",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'rest_framework_simplejwt',
     'corsheaders',
    'campus_services',
    'edu_admin',
    'interaction',
    'tools',
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'tools.User'

# Application definition
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',  
        'PASSWORD': '',  
        'HOST': '',  
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
           'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
       )
   }

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': "this is my SIGNING_KEY",
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}

The main structure is as follows. User in models.py
├─backend
│  │  asgi.py
│  │  routing.py
│  │  settings.py
│  │  urls.py
│  │  wsgi.py
│  │  __init__.py
│    
├─tools
│  │  admin.py
│  │  apps.py
│  │  tests.py
│  │  views.py
│  │  __init__.py
│  │
│  ├─migrations
│  │
│  ├─models
│  │  │  models.py
│  │  │  __init__.py
│  ├─urls
│  │  │  index.py
│  │  │  __init__.py

models.py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('email error')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('username error')
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **extra_fields)
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = bcrypt.hashpw(raw_password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')
        self._password = raw_password

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
        app_label = 'tools'


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    model = User
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password', 'avatar', 'status', 'role', 'is_active', 'is_staff')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser')}
        ),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'username')
    ordering = ('email',)

There is admin.py in tools:
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

When run python manage.py makemigrations  and # AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'tools.User，it happened below,
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'tools.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'tools.User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'tools.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'tools.User.user_permissions'.
tools.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'tools.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'tools.User.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
tools.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'tools.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'tools.User.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.

I hope you can provide me with a solution to this problem or other ways to implement my ideas.

According to the official documentation, UserAdmin (BaseUserAdmin) needs to be placed in the admin.py of tools, not in its models.py file, using admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin) in admin.py, and then executing python manage.py makemigrations, it works for me.
